# Track Facebook Wall Post existence through iPhone app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a general question. I am working on an iPhone App where we post certain things on a user's Facebook wall. We want to track if the exact post made the user still exist the day after. Basically, I want to find out if its possible to check whether a certain post that is made through our App still exist on Facebook or not?

If anyone has an answer for this that would be great!

Comment: Store the post's ID and check https://graph.facebook.com/<ID> later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you publish a post, a `post_id` is returned in the response. ([Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/feed/#pubresponse))

With this post_id, you can make a `\GET` request to `/post-id` and if you don't get the error, that means the post is still there. Or, you can simply check this link: http://facebook.com/{post-id} as @ceejayoz has mentioned.

Comment: Something new came up. Is it possible to check the existence of the post even if we are not friends on Facebook? Basically, through our App, users login with Facebook and make a post to their Facebook wall through our App. Our App, needs to find out if the post still exist at a certain time. Just wondering if this is still possible?

Comment: Yes you can - use the `APP access token` and make the `/GET` request for the `post-id` :)

Comment: o.k..sorry to bother again but our developer mentions that it only works if we have permission to read the post. Meaning, the user has his privacy settings in Facebook set up to allow the public or friends to access and view his post. Not sure if this is true. Just double checking.

Comment: Again, our main goal here is that if someone posts a new post to their Facebook wall through our App, and our App is not related or friends with the user on Facebook, we want to track if the post still exist after a certain action executed within our App.If for instance the user sets's his privacy settings for Posts to "Only Me" or "Friends", are we able to track the post for its existence?